# Apply function to complex subset in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

I'm new to `data.table` and I'd like to get better as I enter the realm of truly big datasets.

I'm trying calculate yearly means for a variable `x`, but from Jun (year y -1) to Jun (year y). This is easy using `plyr`:

```
set.seed(9)

dat = data.frame(
  year = rep(2000:2010, each = 12),
  month = 1:12,
  x = runif(12*length(2000:2010))
)

library(plyr)

ldply(unique(dat$year), function(i) 

  if(i == unique(dat$year)[1]) NULL else # in the event going too far back

    data.frame(
      year = i,
      mean.x = mean(c(dat[dat$year == (i - 1) & dat$month == 7:12, "x"], dat[dat$year == i & dat$month == 1:6, "x"]))
    )

)
```

But I'm struggling to convert the syntax into `data.table`. I'd prefer to do it without creating an intermediate variable for year shifting everything 6 months forward, as there are some variables I would like to summarize in their original Jan-Dec framing.

Any help is appreciated! Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `data.table`, we `shift` the 'year' by 6, use that as grouping variable, and get the `mean` of 'x'

```
setDT(dat)[, .(Mean = mean(x)) ,.(year = shift(year, 6)+1)][-c(1L,.N)]
#  year      Mean
# 1: 2001 0.5086499
# 2: 2002 0.5197482
# 3: 2003 0.6547623
# 4: 2004 0.5869022
# 5: 2005 0.4502414
# 6: 2006 0.5000369
# 7: 2007 0.4514377
# 8: 2008 0.4566757
# 9: 2009 0.3844152
#10: 2010 0.5635942
```

Comment: So the 6 in `shift` refers to the number of rows to offset the data? Hmm, I like.

Comment: @jslefche  Yes, you are right.  I am getting the same output as you showed with `ldply`

Comment: why not change `-c(1,11)` to `-c(1L,.N)` ?

Comment: @jangorecki  Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1):

Dplyr provides a straightforward solution. Essentially, create a dummy variable of relative year - the year you are going to group on - then group, summarize, and make your year column have the right name again.

```
library(dplyr)


summaryDat <- dat %>%

  #assign relative year for calculation
  mutate(relYear = ifelse(month>6, year+1, year)) %>%

  #now group on relative year
  group_by(relYear) %>%

  #get your mean
  summarize(mean_x = mean(x)) %>%

  #now ungroup
  ungroup() %>%

  #format year nicely
  rename(year = relYear)
```

Comment: Note, you could have made this more compact with the mutate statement directly overwriting year, but, I didn't want to do that in case you wanted to do something else with year. But it would eliminate the last `rename` line.